# Find multiple non-matching cells and copy to new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, scripting

I would like to compare cells in Worksheet 2 against Worksheet 1.

First check for matching cells in range A for both Worksheets 1 and 2.

Next, if there are no matches, check for matching cells in range B for both Worksheets 1 and 2, otherwise if there are matches, check the next cell in range A.

If there are no matches as well, copy these non-matching cells in ranges A and B in Worksheet 2 to a new worksheet, Worksheet 3.

Here are my worksheets' layout:

Worksheet 1 -

[image]

Worksheet 2 -

[image]

Worksheet 3 -

[image]

Here is my code (which is not working as intended):

```
Dim Cl As Range, Rng As Range, Dic As Object

Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

With Dic
For Each Cl In MyWorkSheet1Name.Range("A2:B" & MyWorkSheet1Name.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .Item(Cl.Value) = Empty
Next Cl
For Each Cl In MyWorkSheet2Name.Range("A2:B" & MyWorkSheet2Name.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not .Exists(Cl.Value) Then
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = Cl Else Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cl)
    End If
Next Cl
End With

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.EntireRow.Copy MyWorkSheet3Name.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
End If
```

How do I get the code to run as intended?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long

lRow1 = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Sheets(2).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets(3)
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:B" & lRow1).Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")
    Sheets(2).Range("A2:B" & lRow2).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & lRow1 + 1)
    
    .Range("C2").Formula = "=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$" & lRow1 + lRow2 - 1 & ",A2,$B$2:$B$" & lRow1 + lRow2 - 1 & ",B2)"
    .Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C2:C" & lRow1 + lRow2 - 1)
    
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">1"
    .Rows("2:" & lRow1 + lRow2 - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    .Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution!